# How can I convert a string into a math expression in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write an Oracle SQL query that can take a dynamically-generated string and convert it to a mathematical expression, for example: '1*2*1*3*2' would evaluate to 12.

I have done Google searches, but the only Oracle-specific examples I can find are ones that require using a PL/SQL Stored Function.  That isn't an option for me, because I do not have 'CREATE' privileges on my organization's production database.  Since I often need to troubleshoot SQL code against the production DB, I avoid using Stored Procedures or Stored Functions in my report development tool (LogiInfo).

So...what I am hoping to find is some type of 'built-in' function I can place directly into an SQL statement, that will perform the conversion and evaluation described in my opening sentence.  Any guidance will be appreciated.

P.S. I am using Oracle 11g

Comment: What you want is called a parser and it's not a trivial task.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but I figured I may as well ask just in case; thanks for replying.

Answer (score 6):

If you can use SQLPLus you can execute anonymous plsql blocks of code.

Example:

```
set serveroutput on

declare
   i pls_integer;
begin
   execute immediate 'select 1*2*1*3*2 from dual'
      into i;
   dbms_output.put_line(i);
end;
/
```

Comment: Rene, I think I see what you're saying: If I used a stored function to do this, I could copy the source code from the development database and run it in SQL*Plus against the production DB?  That would only work if I was testing that single line of code; I would need to test it in conjunction with other PL/SQL functions.

Comment: Rene, I think I see what you're saying: If I used a stored function to do this, I could copy the source code from the development database and run it in SQL*Plus against the production DB?  That would only work if I was testing that single line of code; I would need to test it in conjunction with other [named] PL/SQL functions. The Logi tool uses SQL statements embedded in an XML file, I can either run straight SQL (my preference) or I can call a stored procedure that is part of a Package, that contains all of the SQL logic and function calls within it.  It's an all-or-nothing choice.

Comment: All I'm saying is that you can run PLSQL code without having CREATE privileges.

Comment: OK, I'll have a closer look at SQL*Plus.  I have been building all of my Oracle queries using SQLDeveloper.  Thanks for replying.